# Light follow camera in viewport3D

Tags: wpf, viewport3d

Is there a way to set  ANY light to follow the camera.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in XAML.
Bind the location to the Camera's location and add an offset by adding a TranslateTransform.

Be careful what you bind to though. If you are moving the camera by using a transform of the camera you will need to bind to the transformation of the camera, not the location.